# Swift | Network call in background thread timing out instantly

Tags: swift, multithreading, networking, usernotifications

I have a native network call configured whenever the app receives a new silent notification, it triggers setAction() which is a POST request that send info related from the notification just received to our own server, in foreground the network call works as expected, the issue comes only when the application is in background. I'm 100% sure that the setAction is being called, but **it looks like at soons as it start dataTask it timesout the network call**, I've tried working with threads, but I'm not sure the issue is there.

Notes:

- To make sure it wasn't a Network issue, I also tried other HTTP request call configuration
- If I send quickly 2 silent notifications, it gets 1 setAction() triggered

  ```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification         userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    // Network call
    tellMe.setAction()

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
  ```

  }

Some of the "log" I've been able to retreive (real https URL being hidden for eg purposes).

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2103, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <92F80B2F-3D6A-4089-AC76-D160B584712C>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <92F80B2F-3D6A-4089-AC76-D160B584712C>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://actualURL.com, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://actualURL.com, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}
The request timed out.
```

Thank you all in advance,

Comment: You are calling `completionHandler` before your network request has finished. That tells the OS that it’s free to suspend your app again. Defer this call until your network request has finished (but definitely call it within 30 seconds or bad things will happen).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the completionHandler was being called before the http request even get time to get called. The fix was to add more time, as the following (not the most beautiful implementation, but it works),

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        
        // Network call
        tellMe.setAction()
        
        let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
        if state == .background {
            //print("App in Background")
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 29) {
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
            }
        } else {
            //print("App in Foreground or Active")
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can avoid waiting the whole 29 seconds: Make a dispatch_group & store it e.g. as a property on app delegate. enter the group (dispatch_group_enter...) before making the network call, have the network call leave the dispatch group on success or failure and dispatch_group_wait (on a bg thread) with a timeout of 29, and call the completion handler